# Can't access youtube embedded iframe with api call pauseVideo

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

With a custom button I want to pause the following embedded youtube video:

```
<iframe id="video1" width="970" height="546" src="https://youtube.com/embed/9IYRC7g2ICg?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=9IYRC7g2ICg&showinfo=0&modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now when the custom pause button get clicked, it should pause the video:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var ytplayer = new YT.Player('video1');
     $.getScript("http://www.youtube.com/player_api");

     $('#button').click(function() {
        ytplayer.pauseVideo();
     });
    });
</script>
```

I got the feeling that this line somehow fails:

```
var ytplayer = new YT.Player('video1');
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues in terms of the order of your script commands. First of all, when you're creating the YT.player object, that has to take place after Google's YouTube API library has already loaded. To ensure this, when you load the library it will call a function named 'onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, a function which you need to define. The trick, though, is that the function has to be defined outside of jQuery's document.ready() function (so that it's in place when the script loads and tries to call it). Like this:

```
var ytplayer;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.getScript("http://www.youtube.com/player_api");
      $('#button').click(function() {
        ytplayer.pauseVideo();
      });
 });

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   ytplayer = new YT.Player('video1', {});
 }
```

Also, in your iFrame, change the src script to include the www subdomain (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/embed/...) so as to avoid the potential of getting your api calls rejected if the domains don't exactly match.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/wshkd1h6/2/) to demonstrate.